# Are these fruit flies, fungus gnats or something else?

Tags: identification, bugs

I've compared to images of both, but they don't exactly match either. If I had to guess, I would say they look more like fruit flies. But, the colony seems to collapse (no longer buzzing around my head all day long) whenever I spray our indoor plant's soil with pyrethrin. I have previously seen bugs flying around the plants. But, these are observations over months. It's entirely possible I'm dealing with different types of bugs over time. These bugs were murdered with an apple cider vinegar / soap combo.

These appear as:

- Tan, to slightly reddish in color with darker abdomens
- Abdomens appear to have black striations
- I don't see anything that suggests there are large red eyes
- The abdomens are as wide as the head then taper to a point rather abruptly

I think they look very much like these drosophila: https://www.google.com/search?q=drosophila

One picture is from a live one that landed on my computer screen last night.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know what they are but I agree they are not fruit flies or gnats. They look larger than a typical fruit fly - do you think that is true?